# Chrome forcing SVG background size. Why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, background-image

So, in my HTML structure, what I have:

```
<div class="card-02">
   <div class="canvas"></div>
</div>
```

And in my CSS, I have:

```
.card-02 {
   transform: rotate(10deg);
   width: 60px;
   height: 90px;
   padding: 3px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 10px; }

.canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(../images/cards-0deg.svg);
   background-size: 2808px 84px;
   background-position: 0 0; }
```

On Mozilla Firefox and before Google's last update, both PNG and SVG worked well.

**PNG (how it should work):**

[image]

**SVG:**

[image]

**The SVG file looks like this:**

[image]

Did something change in the last update to make things this way now? How could I fix it?

Comment: Rather than relying on the viewBox for sizing, have you tried giving the svg a width/height of 2808px x 84px?

Comment: Wow, it worked. Well done, sir!

Comment: No worries, Ha! I was just reading https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/ and actually thought of this question - what timing! Anyhoo - the method seems interesting, but the reason I thought of this was some of the comments from amelia - she's noted bugs with chrome's handling of coord spaces - I guess some problems still exist - some ~2 years later. :( Still though - it may be a method you could make use of - having a single svg file would be nice, just referring to the different parts by id seems easy enough. Also, see: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-svg-icons/

Comment: Oh :( It makes sense. I used the file Adobe Illustrator generated for me, so I couldn't imagine what was wrong in first place.  Thank you!